# Get the list of all connected computers on a server?

Tags: networking

I wanna know how many PC's and the IP address of those PC's that are connected to a Linux server. Any tool I can use or any python script I could make to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Be it. Sorry guys, never really realized this is too hard. I'm trying to google this up, and all I'm finding is using some 'Hacker's' tools. God's sake I better get paid for this :D

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I want, I want to know the list of PCs that are connected to a Linux server (not my machine)

Comment: I tried to search sniff in google, well think it is :D

Comment: DO you know any Tool to be used and command for this thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the server in question is not the authors and they have the appropriate permissions to accomplish their task.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the traffic of someone's else server unless you have the privileges. You might be looking for this:

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

This will list all the IP address on port 80 which are connected to your linux server.

Referene: [list ip addresses connected to your server](https://www.mkyong.com/linux/list-all-ip-addresses-connected-to-your-server/)!

Comment: hahaha, it's some sort of a review that we are doing, this is my part (never thought this would be hard), anyway thanks, I tried searching google though about sniffing as said in the comments above, but no Idea where to start